# Remove duplicates ignoring specific columns

Tags: bash, awk, duplicates, unix-text-processing

I want to remove all duplicates from a file but ignoring the first 2 columns, I mean don't comparing those columns.

This is my example input:

```
111  06:22  apples, bananas and pears
112  06:28  bananas
113  07:07  apples, bananas and pears
114  07:23  apples and bananas
115  08:01  bananas and pears
116  08:23  pears
117  09:22  apples, bananas and pears
118  12:23  apples and bananas
```

I want this output:

```
111  06:22  apples, bananas and pears
112  06:28  bananas
114  07:23  apples and bananas
115  08:01  bananas and pears
116  08:23  pears
```

I've tried this bellow, but it only compares the third column and ignores the rest of the line:

```
awk '!seen[$3]++' sample.txt
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="  "} !seen[$3]++' sample.txt`?

Comment: @Cyrus  Or simply `awk -F "  " ...` granting no two spaces occur in the other columns.

Comment: Are those blanks or tabs between field 1 and field 2, and between field 2 and field 3?

Comment: @Cyrus why not post [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290443/remove-duplicates-ignoring-specific-columns#comment132855805_75290443) as an answer? It might be the best one depending on what separates those fields.

Comment: @EdMorton: I have since used my comment [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75315505/3776858) (same problem) as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `$0` to a temporary variable, set `$1` and `$2` to empty, then use newly composed `$0` as key:

```
awk '{ t = $0; $1 = $2 = "" } !seen[$0]++ { print t }' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`substr` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to get desired part of line for comparison, let `file.txt` content be

```
111  06:22  apples, bananas and pears
112  06:28  bananas
113  07:07  apples, bananas and pears
114  07:23  apples and bananas
115  08:01  bananas and pears
116  08:23  pears
117  09:22  apples, bananas and pears
118  12:23  apples and bananas
```

then

```
awk '!arr[substr($0,11)]++' file.txt
```

gives output

```
111  06:22  apples, bananas and pears
112  06:28  bananas
114  07:23  apples and bananas
115  08:01  bananas and pears
116  08:23  pears
```

Explanation: get lines which are unique by getting substring of whole line (`$0`) starting at 11th character.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*