# Removing Duplicate Domain URLs From the Text File Using Bash

Tags: python, bash, awk

Text file

```
https://www.google.com/1/
https://www.google.com/2/
https://www.google.com
https://www.bing.com
https://www.bing.com/2/
https://www.bing.com/3/
```

Expected Output:

```
https://www.google.com/1/
https://www.bing.com
```

What I Tried

```
awk -F'/' '!a[$3]++' $file;
```

Output

```
https://www.google.com/1/
https://www.google.com
https://www.bing.com
https://www.bing.com/2/
```

I already tried various codes and none of them work as expected. I just want to pick only one unique domain URL per domain from the list.

Please tell me how I can do it by using the Bash script or Python.

PS: I want to filter and save full URLs from the list and not only the root domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` and `/` as field separator:

```
awk -F '/' '!seen[$3]++' file
```

If your file contains Windows line breaks (carriage returns) then I suggest:

```
dos2unix < file | awk -F '/' '!seen[$3]++'
```

Output:

```
https://www.google.com/1/
https://www.bing.com
```

Comment: This is the output I got when I ran the above script.

`https://www.google.com/1/
https://www.google.com
https://www.bing.com
https://www.bing.com/2/`

Comment: I assume that your file contains Windows line breaks (carriage returns). I suggest in this case: `dos2unix < file | awk -F '/' '!seen[$3]++'`

Comment: Thanks. That worked as I expected. Please update your main answer, and I will mark it as resolved.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I'm glad to see it's working. I have added to my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Python solution using one of [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse), let `file.txt` content be

```
https://www.google.com/1/
https://www.google.com/2/
https://www.google.com
https://www.bing.com
https://www.bing.com/2/
https://www.bing.com/3/
```

then

```
from itertools import filterfalse
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBcCAD', str.lower) --> A B c D
    seen = set()
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen.add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen.add(k)
                yield element


def get_netloc(url):
    return urlparse(url).netloc

with open("file.txt","r") as fin:
    with open("file_uniq.txt","w") as fout:
        for line in unique_everseen(fin,key=get_netloc):
            fout.write(line)
```

creates file `file_uniq.txt` with following content

```
https://www.google.com/1/
https://www.bing.com
```